# Sails.js and pluralized relational database table names

Tags: sails.js, waterline

How do I configure Sails.js / Waterline to default to pluralized relational database table names that correspond to singular models (same as Rails)?

(E.g. A model called 'Person' should default to a PostgreSQL table called 'people'.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add the `tableName: 'people'` property to the model:

```
// Person.js    

module.exports = {

  tableName: 'people',

  attributes: {

    id: 'integer',

    name: 'string'

  }

};
```

There does not appear to be a global setting in Sails.js that pluralizes database table names automatically for models with singular names.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this in your `blueprints.js` or `local.js` file:

```
blueprints: { // if in your local.js wrap in this object
  pluralize: true
}
```

It won't get it right every time, so the `tableName` property is still useful for odd cases, but for most pluralized terms it will work.